# IS GCM A CLOUD ENDPOINT OR SEPARATE ENTITY?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new to android development,I am working on push notification app now and trying to get overview of concepts about GCM and got stuck with one of the concept about use of "endpoint".

I am going through below google developer link:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addgcm

they have given something like this

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)allows your Cloud Endpoints to send
>   notifications to registered Android devices whenever the state of a
>   resource changes. For example, suppose a user uses a Note application
>   from 2 devices: Device A and Device B. If the user is adding a note
>   from Device A. Google Cloud Messaging can be used in the Cloud
>   Endpoint for the insert operation to ping Device B to indicate that a
>   note has been added.

my questions are

1>> Is GCM itself an endpoint?or it is a separate entity?

2>> how to interact with 3rd party app server without using endpoint for server and client?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM and Cloud Endpoints are separate and unrelated Google services (though one possible source of confusion is that the term 'endpoint' is often also used in more generic ways).

Endpoints is a service for creating public API's for GAE app's.  It can make it easier to create the API's that will allow your clients to communicate with your GAE app, particularly if those clients are iOS, Android, or Web apps (the supported client types), and if you want to use OAuth2 authentication for the apps or their users.

GCM is for waking up, and pushing data to, your apps on those same platforms.  It is true that your server app will probably use both GCM and Endpoints, they are separate and unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me . Can you tell me the case scenario when cloud endpoints are use and how? and gcm also use services of cloud endpoint to send data to Android app?

Comment: Endpoints is used where you want the app to call the server.  GCM is for when the server initiates the communications.  In that way, they serve similar but opposite purpose.  I suggest you start with Endpoints on the server, and Volley in your Android app, and only worry about GCM later if you find you need your server to initiative comm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.volley for android means Android Volley Library?Can You explain me how Up streaming (from client to gcm(intermediate)to 3rd party app server) take place and here where Endpoint comes in the picture means flow of events  ?i am asking this because on https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html link they have mention that GCM Cloud Connection Server (CCS) is an XMPP endpoint.

Comment: Yes, volley is a good way to create and manage the requests that an Android client would send to a GAE endpoint.  As for the rest, you are going to need to create a new question and come up with a more focussed question.

Comment: thank you vary much for your advice .can you suggest me some tutorial where i can find how to implement  server(app engine api endpoint) and android client (using volley library) and make some communication between server and android app.

Comment: as i am going through your answer on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782186/how-do-i-make-requests-from-an-android-app-to-an-app-engine-backend) t make sense now use of volley library on android application is easy way to communicating from android app to server(app on app engine).Bt can you provide me some tutorial by which I can make a server and web base client in eclipse .I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know of any such tutorials off hand - plz search for them.